# How to calculate interst polymorphically/inheritance

Tags: java

I've been able to read in the text file line by line and splitting it using the split method and then putting it in an ArrayList of obects. I can reprint the data on the screen and now I need to POLYMORPHICALLY/USING INHERITANCE (depending on the type B or C or S) calculate the interest and print it out next to type.  How do I do this?  If someone can provide a code example that would be much appreciated! I am guessing I have to create one class for business, checking, and saving and extend it from my accounts class (which has all my methods) and in each write up a method that says calculate interest but I don't know what to exactly do from there

Here is my code for the two classes

Main program

```
List<accounts_class> bank_data = new ArrayList<accounts_class>();
try
{
  String thisline = null;
  FileReader fr = new FileReader("banking.txt");
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( fr);
  while((thisline=br.readLine()) != null)
  {

     String[] array=thisline.split("\t");   //it goes from array[0] to array[5]
     accounts_class bank_info = new accounts_class();
     bank_info.set_name(array[0]);
     bank_info.set_account_number(array[1]);
     bank_data.add(bank_info);

  }
  fr.close();
}
catch (Exception e)                                                           
{
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
} 

for (accounts_class bank_info : bank_data)
{

   System.out.println(bank_info.get_name() + "\t" 
      + bank_info.get_account_number() + "\t" 
   }
```

and my methods class code is this: 
    private String name;

```
public String get_name() {return name;}

public void set_balance(double balance)
{
   this.balance = balance;

}


      //have methods for all fields like this and then have get_balance, get_account_type, get_phone....etc same thing for set_name too and all others.
```

And I created a class for business, savings, and checking which extends this clas but nothing is in there right now. I will put a method to calculate interest in there to individually calculate the interest for each account type -- remember i need to do this program polymorphically/using inheritance.

Comment: In your base account class, just add an abstract method `calculateInterest`. Then you'll just need to implement it for each of the account types.

Comment: what do you mean....I am not sure how that would be considered polymorphic though...maybe a code might be more explanatory ...thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public abstract class accounts_class {
    private String account_number;
    private String name;
    private String phone_number;
    private String ssn;
    private double balance;
    private String account_type;

    public String get_name()
         {
    {return name;}

    public void set_balance(double balance)
    {


       this.balance = balance;

    }

    public abstract double computeInterest();
}
```

Now implement the abstract method `computeInterest()` in your sub classes(business, savings, and checking). Thus, you can implement both inheritance and polymorphism.

Comment: okay but what do I do in the main class....how does it determine to use the computeinterest method in the checking class or business class or saving class.....there must be something I need to do

Comment: @User2817778 The calling code will have an array of classes that inherit from accounts_class. You simply loop through the array calling computeInterest(). Java will figure out which method to call based on what the class is.

Comment: You can create objects of different accounts and assign them to account_class reference.
When the `computeInterest()` method is called on the `account_class` reference, java compiler allows it to compile since `computeInterest()` method is present in account_class. But at runtime, JVM resolves the method call based on the type of object calling the method(runtime polymorphism). Thus, you can implement both inheritance and polymorphism.